# Vb.net cant save picture using the ms.access Database

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, visual-studio-2012, ms-access-2016

Okay please forgive me if this sound annoying but i keep getting an error nullreference whenever im trying to input my data.. Im sorry if im doing this wrong This is my first time posting here :

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class halaman_daftar_anggota

Dim Conn As OleDbConnection
Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter
Dim ds As DataSet
Dim CMD As OleDbCommand

Dim bytimage As Byte()

Dim LokasiDB As String
Sub Koneksi()
    LokasiDB = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=perpustakaan.accdb"
    Conn = New OleDbConnection(LokasiDB)
    If Conn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then Conn.Open()
End Sub
Private Sub halaman_daftar_anggota_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Koneksi()
    da = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from data_anggota", Conn)
    ds = New DataSet
    ds.Clear()
    da.Fill(ds, "data_anggota")
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim dialog As OpenFileDialog = New OpenFileDialog()

    dialog.Title = "Browse Foto"
    dialog.Filter = "image files(*.png; *.bmp; *.jpg;*.jpeg; *.gif; |*.png; *.bmp; *.jpg;*.jpeg; *.gif;)"
    If dialog.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(dialog.FileName)
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Try
        Dim ms As New System.IO.MemoryStream
        Dim bmpimage As New Bitmap(PictureBox1.Image)

        bmpimage.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
        bytimage = ms.ToArray()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
    Call Koneksi()
    Dim simpan As String = "INSERT INTO data_buku (nomor_induk,nama_siswa,kelas_siswa,foto) values ('" & TextBox1.Text & "','" & TextBox2.Text & "','" & TextBox3.Text & "','" & TextBox4.Text & "',@image)"
    CMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@image", bytimage) <-"Error object reference not set to an instance of an object"
    CMD = New OleDbCommand(simpan, Conn)
    CMD.ExecuteNonQuery()
    MsgBox("Berhasil")
End Sub
End Class
```

Whenever im trying to save a picture.in my database j already set foto as ole object... Im sorry..

Comment: You're trying to add parameters to a Command before you have created the Command. The DataAdapter and DataSet are also created new each time, so you don't actually use these objects for what they're for, so a Field for these is also useless. The method that fills the DataSet should be a Function that returns a DataTable instead. BTW, you shouldn't try to store either the Connection or the Command. A byte array Field that contains the Image bytes makes sense, if you stored the image bytes when you first load the Bitmap. Otherwise, it's useless. -- You should also avoid `AddWithValue()` here.

Comment: Thank you mr.jimi for helping me... Sorry for disturbing you sir. Too bad i cant give answer to an comment.... Once again im very grateful